# Regular expression to capture this text from a list

Tags: php, regex

The text I have:

```
URL: http://example.com
Type: department
Empty value:
Contact Name: John Doe
...
```

I want to get an array like this:

```
array(
  'url'           => 'http://example.com',
  'type'          => 'department',
  'empty-value'   => '',
  'contact-mame'  => 'John Doe'
)
```

I was doing something like

```
preg_match_all( '/(url|type): (.*)/i', $string, $match );
```

But $match doesn't have the values in the order I need and I don't know how to capture the keys.

The conversion to lowercase keys and dashes doesn't matter at this time.

Can you suggest any regex pattern?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` and `array_combine`:

```
$s = <<< EOF
URL: http://example.com
Type: department
Empty value:
Contact Name: John Doe
EOF;

preg_match_all('~^([^:]+):\h*(.*)$~m', $s, $matches);
$output = array_combine ( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
print_r( $output );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [URL] => http://example.com
    [Type] => department
    [Empty value] =>
    [Contact Name] => John Doe
)
```